# My android studio doesn't show a new directory

Tags: android, android-studio

This is how it looks: 
[image]

and when I create a new subdirectory this way

[image]

the newly created directory doesn't show up under 'res.'

But if I go to the physical location of res, 
AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/res

There is a new folder with the name under which I created a directory.

Why is it happening?

I closed and restarted android studio, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: change perspective, from android to one of the others and you'll find it

Comment: change the perspective. Use "Project" instead of "Android"

Comment: Is there a way to see it without having to change the perspective? When I hit package, I can see it, but I would like to see it under res in Android instead of Package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio --> Project Tab on Left side --> Choose Project from Spinner, not Android Item. And You can add folder. If It is not clear, I can share picture for more.

Comment: When I select packages, I can see the folder that I created, but not under res. Is there a way to see the folder without changing it to package?